# How to use a Primary Key also as a Foreign Key reference with JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, orm

I'd like to create a table where the `primary key` of an object should also serve as the `foreign key` for two `@ManyToOne` tables.

Is that possible without creating extra table columns both referencing and repeating the same primary key id?

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private int personId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_address_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_address"))
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_location_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_location"))
    private Location location;
}
```

Problem: the `@Id` for `Address` and `Location` is always the same as `@Id` from `Person`.
The mapping above will cause hibernate to generate 3 columns. `id, fk_address, fk_location`, where each of the columns have the same value (the id).

Question: is it possible to just having the `primary key` @Id for the person, and at the same time tell hibernate that this is the foreign key for some more `@ManyToOne` foreign key mappings, without these columns being created?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594577/hibernate-how-to-map-two-many-to-many-to-the-same-entity/29603999#29603999) post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have a one-to-one association between `Person`, `PersonAddress`, and `PersonLocation`, you need to use `@MapsId` JPA annotation because [it is the best way to map a one-to-one table relationship](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

I added an example [on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/association/TwoMapsIdsTest.java) for this. Basically, you can map those associations like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public class Person  {

    @Id
    private Long personId;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
    private PersonAddress address;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
    private PersonLocation location;
}
```